# What is the regular expression in Jmeter for a dynamic string?

Tags: regex, performance, jmeter, performance-testing, correlation

This is getting generated in a request output in Jmeter and I need to capture the dynamic value.

```
<update id="javax.faces.ViewState"><![CDATA[-8480553014738537212:-8925834053543623028]]></update>
```

the - (hyphen) symbol coming in the output is also dynamic.

I have tried handling this using

```
<update id="javax.faces.ViewState"><![CDATA[(.+?)]]></update>
```

But this is not helping. Please suggest.

Comment: The `[` must be escaped in a regular expression. BTW, why not use [XPath Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor)?

Comment: @Wiktor Stribizew.. The [  is coming in the output and we need to capture the value inside []

Comment: The `[`s are part of the CData block. If you use XPath Extractor, it will parse XML correctly, and you will be able to get this value with a mere `//update[@id='javax.faces.ViewState']/text()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to grab the data is by using the [XPath Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor) with the following XPath:

```
//update[@id='javax.faces.ViewState']/text()
```

It gets the `update` tags that have `id` attribute with the `javax.faces.ViewState` value and extracts the text from these nodes.

Your regex is not correct because the `[` (and literal dots) must be escaped in the regular expressions, and can be fixed as `<update\s+id="javax\.faces\.ViewState"><!\[CDATA\[([^\]<]+)]]></update>`. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SGqQT3/1).